# Android USB Permissions, onPause, onResume - Unfortunately, System UI has stopped"

Tags: java, usb, android-studio, intentfilter, android-permissions

I am developing an Android application using Android Studio 0.5.2.

My application is operating a USB host which appears to operate correctly - unless the device is connected (and permissions have not yet been granted) when the app starts.

Generally, what happens when the USB is connected (while app is running):

- "onResume" is called - this detects the device and asks for permission.  An intent filter is created to catch when the USB is attached, detached or permission granted
- Permission request is shown, select Ok
- "onResume" is called again.  The first line of this funciton is "super.onResume()"
- As soon as I step over super.onResume, "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped" message is displayed and the Android UI crashes
- My application continues to work correctly

If I connect the device while the application is already running there is no issue - this only occurs when the USB is connected on launch.

Any insight into what could be causing this or how to further narrow down on the problem would be greatly appreciated.  I have attached the notable code below.  I am not normally a Java developer, so I suspect the issue is something to do with the pause/resume behaviour, receivers, intent filters or permissions.

```
// *************************************************************
// ************************* USB Stuff *************************
// *************************************************************
boolean resumePermissionBlocked = false;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get the information about what action caused this event
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.i(TAG, "$EC: action:" + action);

            if ("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION".equals(action)) {
                UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if (device != null) {


                        if (device.getProductId() == 0xAAAA) {
                            if (device.getVendorId() == 0xBBBB) {
                                // see if we have permission
                                UsbManager openManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

                                // send a message to the worker thread to begin opening a connection to this device
                                ThreadMsg msg = new ThreadMsg();
                                msg.request = MsgRequest.openConnection;
                                msg.objectA = device;
                                msg.objectB = openManager;
                                sendMessageToWorker(msg);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (device != null)
                        Log("USB Permission denied", TextFormat.StrongWarning_withTime);
                }
            }
            if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device == null) return;
                if (device.getProductId() == 0x003C) {
                    if (device.getVendorId() == 0x04D8) {
                        // see if we have permission
                        UsbManager openManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                        if (!openManager.hasPermission(device)) {
                            resumePermissionBlocked = true; // block the resume function from trying to re-ask for permission
                            openManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
                            return;
                        }
                        ThreadMsg msg = new ThreadMsg();
                        msg.request = MsgRequest.openConnection;
                        msg.objectA = device;
                        msg.objectB = openManager;
                        sendMessageToBootloader(msg);
                    }
                }
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                // If it was a USB device detach event, then get the USB device
                // that caused the event from the intent.
                UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                ThreadMsg msg = new ThreadMsg();
                msg.request = MsgRequest.closeConnection;
                msg.objectA = device;
                sendMessageToBootloader(msg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResume catch: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

};

boolean receiverHasBeenRegistered = false;

PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
@Override
public void onResume(){
    try {

        super.onResume();

        if (resumePermissionBlocked) {
            // this was resumed from a permission request - don't try to connect to the device now, leave it for the USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED intent
            resumePermissionBlocked = false;    // clear the flag
        } else {
            UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
            if (deviceList != null) {
                Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
                Log.i(TAG, "$EC: Begin iteration");

                while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                    // Is this the device we are after?
                    UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
                    if (device == null) return;
                    if (device.getProductId() == 0xAAAA) {
                        if (device.getVendorId() == 0xBBBB) {
                            // see if we have permission
                            UsbManager openManager = (UsbManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                            if (!openManager.hasPermission(device)) {
                                resumePermissionBlocked = true;         // block the subsequent call to this (between the application resuming and permission being granted)
                                openManager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
                                return;
                            }
                            ThreadMsg msg = new ThreadMsg();
                            msg.request = MsgRequest.openConnection;
                            msg.objectA = device;
                            msg.objectB = openManager;
                            sendMessageToWorker(msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume catch: " + e.toString());
    }

    if (!receiverHasBeenRegistered) {
        // this line is for permissions
        mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"), 0);

        //Create a new filter to detect USB device events
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
        filter.addAction("com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(getPackageName() + ".USB_PERMISSION"), 0);
        receiverHasBeenRegistered = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    /* unregister any receivers that we have */
    try {
        if (receiver != null && receiverHasBeenRegistered) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            receiverHasBeenRegistered = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if this happens, then the receiver was probably never registered in the first place
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause catch: " + e.toString());
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try super.onResume at the end of onResume method
2. Alert user to connect the usb device on application start (main activity's
   onCreate) if device is not connected, toast an alert msg and finish/close
   the main activity
3. Add intend filter in manifest file allowing the app to start automatically on connecting the device
4. Try to capture exception printstacktrack when the UI stopped message is
   shown and debug further from the exception.
5. Make sure to follow the steps from android doc
   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html